# How can I obtain all of the file names in a directory?

Tags: c++, windows, file, directory

I am writing a program in C++. I am trying to obtain all of the files in the folder where the program executable is located and store them in a vector. I have been told that the following code should work, but the FindFirstFile operation only finds one file (the name of the folder that it should be searching through). How can I change the code so that it looks through the folder properly?

```
std::vector<char*> fileArray;

//Get location of program executable
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameW(hModule, path, MAX_PATH);

//Remove the executable file name from 'path' so that it refers to the folder instead
PathCchRemoveFileSpec(path, sizeof(path));

//This code should find the first file in the executable folder, but it fails
//Instead, it obtains the name of the folder that it is searching
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
hFind = FindFirstFile(path, &ffd);

do
{
    //The name of the folder is pushed onto the array because of the previous code's mistake
    //e.g. If the folder is "C:\\MyFolder", it stores "MyFolder"
    fileArray.push_back(ffd.cFileName); //Disclaimer: This line of code won't add the file name properly (I'll get to fixing it later), but that's not relevant to the question
} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0); //This line fails to find anymore files
```

Comment: Tried putting \\* at the end of the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have been told that the following code should work

You were told wrong, because the code you have presented is severely broken.

> the FindFirstFile operation only finds one file (the name of the folder that it should be searching through).

You are passing just the folder path by itself to `FindFirstFile()`, so only one entry will be reported, describing the folder itself.  What you need to do is append a `*` or `*.*` wildcard to the end of the path, then `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` will enumerate the files and subfolders inside the folder.

Aside from that, there are several other problems with the code.

Even if the enumeration were working, you are not differentiating between files and subfolders.

You are passing a bad value to the second parameter of `PathCchRemoveFileSpec()`.  You are passing in a *byte* count, but it expects a *character* count instead.

You are not checking `FindFirstFile()` for failure before entering your loop, and you are not calling `FindClose()` after the loop is finished.

And lastly, your code won't even compile as-is.  Your `vector` is storing `char*` values, but in order to pass a `WCHAR[]` to `FindFirstFile()`, `UNICODE` has to be defined, which means `FindFirstFile()` will map to `FindFirstFileW()` and `WIN32_FIND_DATA` will map to `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`, and thus the `cFileName` field will be a `WCHAR[]`.  The compiler will not allow a `WCHAR[]` (or `WCHAR*)` to be assigned to a `char*`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> fileArray;

//Get location of program executable
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};
GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);

//Remove the executable file name from 'path' so that it refers to the folder instead
PathCchRemoveFileSpec(path, MAX_PATH);

// append a wildcard to the path
PathCchAppend(path, MAX_PATH, L"*.*");

WIN32_FIND_DATAW ffd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(path, &ffd);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        if ((ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
            fileArray.push_back(ffd.cFileName);
    }
    while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &ffd));
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Comment: This code definitely obtains all of the files accurately, but how would I be able to obtain them in char* form as opposed to wstring?

Comment: If you want your program to work properly, don't.  (What if one of the file names contains a character that isn't in the current code page?)

Comment: @Ben: Harry is right, you really should not Ansi-fy your code. Windows is a Unicode OS, and NTFS uses Unicode filenames. You should be using Unicode for everything. That being said, if you really need the filenames in `char` format instead of `WCHAR`, either use `WideCharToMultiByte()` to convert the filenames from `WCHAR` to `char`, or else use `FindFirstFileA()`/`FindNextFileA()` instead of `FindFirstFileW()`/`FindNextFileW()`...

Comment: @Ben: ... In which case, your `path` would also need to be in `char` format. You can use `GetModuleFileNameA()` for that. `PathCchRemoveFileSpec()` and `PathCchAppend()` do not support `char` data, only `WCHAR` data, but `PathRemoveFileSpecA()` and `PathAppendA()` support `char`.